# How TO Prevent Multiple Entries in my ListBox when selecting Item From a List View

Tags: c#, web-controls

I have a ASP ListView Control that populates data from a SQL Server database, and it is working as designed. I also have a ASP Listbox control that gets populated with the ID and Name from the ListView Control, it is kind of working, that is if I select it it displays as designed, but if I keep selecting the same row from the ListView Control it keeps adding it to the Listbox, this is not what I desire, I would rather it only shows one time no matter how many times I selected the same row from the list view.

This is what I have

```
protected void distList_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex;

    distList.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    rowIndex = distList.SelectedIndex;
    string sapId = distList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    string DistributorName = distList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
    string output = sapId + " " + DistributorName;

    SAPListBox.Items.Add(output);
}
```

I am at a stand still as I been at this all day trying many thing just to get nowhere, I I think I might just be missing something.

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP, please retag.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowIndex;

    distList.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    rowIndex = distList.SelectedIndex;

//You might need to change this, to the listbox rather than a listview. Wasn't quite sure which one you wanted. 
    var txt = rowIndex;
    if (!distlist.Items.ContainsKey(txt))
{


string sapId = distList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    string DistributorName = distList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
    string output = sapId + " " + DistributorName;


    SAPListBox.Items.Add(output);
}
```

Hopefully this helps, if not. It was my best attempt ^^